# replace multiple values with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, replace, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to replace the values in column "Action" to be specific values. My data looks like this:

```
id           ActionName
1         First quartile
2         Midpoint
3         Third quartile
4         Complete
```

I want to replace those values with numbers. Expected output:

```
id          ActionName
1           0
2           1
3           2
4           3
```

I tried the following:

```
df_new = df.withColumn("ActionName", when (col("ActionName").isin("First quartile"), 0), \
                              (col("ActionName").isin("Midpoint"), 1))
```

Error: `TypeError: withColumn() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate `when` to the `when` statement. This is same as `else if`

```
df_new = df.withColumn("ActionName", when(col("ActionName") == "First quartile", 0).when(col("ActionName") == "Midpoint", 1))
```

If you want to have further replacements, you can concatenate more `when` statements, e.g. `when(..., 1).when(..., 2).when(..., 3)`

Comment: I tried running this: ```df_new = df.withColumn("ActionName", when(col("ActionName").isin("First quartile"), 0).\
                                  otherwise(col("ActionName").isin("Midpoint"), 1).\
                                  otherwise(col("ActionName").isin("Third quartile"), 2).\
                                  otherwise(col("ActionName").isin("Complete"), 3))``` But got an error: `TypeError: otherwise() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
`

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer. I forgot about the syntax

Comment: Hmmm I ran the following: ```df_new = df.withColumn("ActionName", when(col("ActionName").isin("First quartile"), 0).\
                                  when(col("ActionName").isin("Midpoint"), 1).\
                                  when(col("ActionName").isin("Third quartile"), 2).\
                                  when(col("ActionName").isin("Complete"), 3))``` And got all nulls in return...

Comment: Ah, you should use `col("ActionName") == "First quartile"`, etc. `isin` is used for columns, not strings.

Comment: @mck just the code i was looking for, can you explain further on when isin is used ?

Comment: @SS_flair it's used when you want to check whether a column is contained in another column(s). See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin